# laravel eloquent query with relations

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I'm trying to replace a mysql query with laravel eloquent. This is my structure.

```
Consumers Table
---------------
id, email, name

Transactions Table
-------------------
id, consumer_id, value, bonus_value
```

Output that I'm trying to achieve

```
id, email, name, total_value
1, abc@123.com, Al, 11000
2, abc2@123.com, Bl, 200000
```

This is what I have added in `Consumer.php`

```
/**
     * Transactions Relationship
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function transactions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'consumer_id');
    }
```

And this is the query I've written so far.

```
$query = Consumer::query()
                ->join('consumer_transactions AS ct', function($q) {
                    $q->on('consumers.id', '=', 'ct.consumer_id')
                        ->where('ct.status', 'processed')
                        ->where('ct.approved', 1)
                        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(ct.value + ct.bonus_value) AS total_points'))
                    ;
                })
                ->whereIn('consumers.id', $consumerIds)
                ->get()
            ;
```

It doesn't return `total_points`

Answer (score 1):

[Join Clause](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html) that passed to your join take  `Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause` witch doesn't have a method called 'select'.

you `select` should be out of join clause.

```
$query = Consumer::query()
                ->join('consumer_transactions AS ct', function($q) {
                    $q->on('consumers.id', '=', 'ct.consumer_id')
                        ->where('ct.status', 'processed')
                        ->where('ct.approved', 1);
                })
 ->select( ['consumers.*', DB::raw('SUM(ct.value + ct.bonus_value) AS total_points')])
                ->whereIn('consumers.id', $consumerIds)
                ->get();
```

Comment: It only shows one record and sums all the transaction values of all consumers. I want to show each consumer's transaction value separately.

Comment: try using leftJoin instead of join

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fun of joining tables. That's why I can offer you a different approach.

```
$consumers = Consumer::whereIn('id', $consumerIds)
                ->with(['transactions' => function($query) {
                    $query
                       ->where('startus', 'processed')
                       ->where('approved', 1)
                }])->get()
                ->map(function($item, $key) {
                   return $item->total_points = $item->transactions->value + $item->transactions->bonus_value
                });
```

Comment: Yeah but I want to add a where clause that compares the total_points like 
`->where('ct.total_points', '>', 5000);`

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You can add filter() function after map(). https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter